# How to convert DataFrame to Iterable (and fill checkbox in Zeppelin with the values)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I want to fill a Checkbox in spark with the distinct values of a column, because in the next step this shall be my filter options.

My data Looks like this:

df:

```
root
 |-- KW: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- grund: long (nullable = true)
 |-- text_rotschaltung: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Anzahl: long (nullable = false)
```

ColumnFilter:

```
root
 |-- grund: long (nullable = true)
```

The column "grund" is an identifier for the reason from failures. And in my report the user shall be filter interactively which reasons he wants to see.

Actually I have this code part:

```
...

    val df = rdd1.toDF()
    var ColumnFilter = df.orderBy("grund").select("grund").distinct



println("Hello "+z.checkbox("The reasons:", ColumnFilter).mkString(" and "))
```

With this code I get the error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 required: Iterable[(Object, String)]
println("Hello "+z.checkbox("The reasons", ColumnFilter).mkString(" and "))
```

How can I convert a DataFrame to Iterable or which other Options have I to fill the Checkbox?

Thank you very much.

Comment: how does youe `z.checkbox` method look like?

Comment: In this Moment I haven´t got a method. So I want to fill it like in this example:

val options = Seq(("apple","Apple"), ("banana","Banana"), ("orange","Orange"))
println("Hello "+z.checkbox("fruit", options).mkString(" and "))

(https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/manual/dynamicform.html)

With the difference, that I use the column.

Comment: Then I think you should update your question with your current input dataframe, how you want your output to look like and what have you tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I convert a DataFrame to Iterable

Use `collect` to get the data back (from inside of `DataFrame`).